# Использование локальных переменных в plsql Developer

Tags: sql, plsql-developer

```
DEFINE TEMP_ID = 1004;
SELECT * FROM FORMATS WHERE FRMT_ID = &TEMP_ID;
```

Почему в командной строке sql plus всё нормально отрабатывает, а когда в plsql Developer я выделяю этот текст в SQL окне, нажимаю F8 чтобы выполнить, то выпрыгивает окошко, которое предлагает выписать значение переменной TEMP_ID? При этом никакую ошибку не выводит. Наличие или отсутствие знака ';' в конце строки ни на что не влияет.

Comment: А если убрать `&`?

Comment: И опубликуйте **оригинальный** текст ошибки вместе с ее кодом

Comment: Попробуйте нажать `F5` вместо `F8`...

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ошибки нет, выскакивает форма для ввода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Define` - это команда `SQLPlus`. `PL\SQL Developer` не поддерживает ее для окон типа `sql window`.
Если вы просто удалите строку с определением(`DEFINE temp_id = 1004;`) то девелопер покажет окно с предложением ввести значение переменной.

Так же вы можете изменить окно на `command window`, в нем у вас будет работать ваш пример.

Comment: Понятно, очень жаль -.- Выходит, придется таки на plsql запилить.